# How to skip the security setting on flash player?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, security, camera, adobe

Can we skip the security setting (for camera permission) on flash player when we attached camera (by code) ? So every time we use the flash app, the permission is always 'allow'. Because I am using camera for local purpose only, so the camera images will not shared to others (standalone app, not web apps). So, the user must not click on it all the time.

[image: security setting]

Is it possible ?

Comment: As @JustinvanWilgen says, you can't force the app to allow access.  However, as shown in the settings dialog, once the dialog is displayed, if the user selects "Remember" the option is remembered for the application.

Comment: Ooo it's not possible then

Answer (score 1):

Something you must understand is that Flash is a sandbox environment, you will not be able to change or influence any client side browser settings.

The best solution for this may be to inform the user via an alert to make sure that there flash security settings are set correctly.

Comment: Ooo it's not possible then